# Form built from database array values is not limiting radio buttons to single selection

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I am trying to build a form where the user selects an item based upon an array of values from a database table.  Here is the code that I am using to filter out the list:

```
$arrlength=count($results);

$listSubscriptions = '<form>';
for($x=0; $x<$arrlength; $x++)
  {
    $itemList =    $results[$x]->item_name;
    $listSubscriptions .= '<input type="radio" name="'.$itemList.'" value="'.$itemList.'"> '.$itemList.'<br>';
  }
  $listSubscriptions .= '</form>';

 return $listSubscriptions;
```

When I print the results of the form I am able to get the radio buttons to display as I would like them to, but the problem is that the selection is not being limited to one radio button selection.  Any ideas why?

Comment: radio button group must have **same "name" attribute**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The radio buttons must all share a single `name` attribute to belong to the same group:

```
$listSubscriptions .= '<input type="radio" name="subscription" value="' . $itemList . '"> ' . $itemList . '<br>';
```